# Javascript: flatten nested JSON array with while keeping a key value

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON array:

```
[{
     "eurusd": {
         "at": 1410438338,
         "ticker": {
             "buy": "1.123",
             "sell": "1.123",
             "low": "1.123",
             "high": "1.123",
             "last": "1.123",
             "vol": "1.123",
             "change": "1.123",
             "change_trend": "up"
         }
     },
     "eurgbp": {
         "at": 1410438338,
         "ticker": {
             "buy": "1.123",
             "sell": "1.123",
             "low": "1.123",
             "high": "1.123",
             "last": "1.123",
             "vol": "1.123",
             "change": "1.123",
             "change_trend": "down"
         }
     }
 }]
```

and need to bring it in the following format:

```
[{
    "market": "eurusd",
    "currency": "usd",
    "volume": "1.123",
    "change": "1.123",
    "last": "1.123",
    "high": "1.123",
    "low": "1.123"
}, {
    "market": "eurgbp",
    "currency": "gbp",
    "volume": "1.123",
    "change": "1.123",
    "last": "1.123",
    "high": "1.123",
    "low": "1.123"
}]
```

I am aware of flatten methods but there is an important thing I can not make work:

1) currency is not part of the original array. I will need to split it from the key name

so far I am able to fully flatten the original array but I have no luck to leave out certain values (eg. buy/sell) as well as adding the "currency" value to the new array.

Comment: Where are you getting the 2.009 for volume in eurusd from? How is it calculated? You need to show what you've done so far, particularly with respect with the algorithm you need to use.

Comment: Andy, the numbers are random

Comment: You should change your question so that the values match in the before/after JSON or you'll have everyone as confused as me.

Comment: @Andy - i have adjusted the numbers. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @domi771 You should indent your array, reading it is really painful.

Comment: @DrGeneral I am sorry - will do it next time. Looks better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't so much want so much to flatten this object as just extract the `ticker` values and add the market information to the individual items. For that, I think you're in need of an ad-hoc approach:

```
var items = [],
    cur,
    ticker,
    item;
for (var cur in data[0]) {
    ticker = data[0][cur].ticker;
    item = {};
    ["change", "last", "high", "low"].forEach(function (key) {
        item[key] = ticker[key];
    });
    item.volume = ticker.vol;
    item.market = cur;
    item.currency = cur.substring(3);
    items.push(item);
}
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thcyejea/1/)

Comment: i try hard with your suggestion but no luck so far ... dont get any error message simply no output in console.log yet. I changed "items" with "markets" both for the var and the markets.push(item) in the end

Comment: Did you do `console.log(markets)` _inside_ the `$.getJSON` callback? Since `getJSON` is asynchronous, `markets` will not be filled until the callback happens.

Comment: What language is that you're using? It doesn't appear to be JavaScript. Can you put it into PasteBin or something? It's hard to see here in the comment box.

Comment: I notice that you're using for `for key of data` rather than `for key of data[0]`. In your original post, it looks like `data` is an array containing one object. Is it actually an object?

Comment: I have adjusted the version on pastebin to the original one from you. Yes i think the problem is that we are talking about objects. See here output from firebug:  `Object {usdeur: Object, usdeur: Object}usdgbp: Objectusdgbp: Object__proto__: Object`

Comment: In that case, it was probably right without the `[0]`. So you're saying that when you do `console.log markets` it shows an empty array? Are you sure that you have enough indentation on `console.log markets`? It looks like it has several fewer spaces before it than the rest of the callback handler does (this is why I really dislike it when languages treat indentation as meaningful).

Comment: thank you for the perfect answer. I have still some coffeescript troubles and will open an other post for those.